# is it grammatically correct? two -ing words together

Tags: grammar

- The situation was going irritating at that time.
- I am starting eating my breakfast now.

Are these statements correct? Can I use two -ing words together? Can you explain by giving few more examples?

Comment: Side note: We don't say "going irritating" but "getting irritating" or "becoming irritating".

Answer (score 6):

There is no rule forbidding two *-ing* forms close or next to each other if the idiom requires it.

> We're going fishing/hunting/dancing.

However, most speakers avoid using similar constructions close to each other, except when they are deliberately emphasizing a parallelism. Consequently, your second example would usually employ a different construction:

> I'm starting **to eat** my breakfast now.

The pressure is not so strong in your first example, however, since *irritating* has today the status of an independent adjective. It has been, as the linguists say, ‘deverbalized’, so it is not perceived as a present participle. “The situation was getting irritating” would not be strenuously avoided.

Comment: I have to disagree.  In my American dialect, the two sentences are  just wrong.  Those second -ing verbs should be infinitives, as KA points out.

Comment: As far as I know there is a rule. Can't remember the name, but according to that rule it's fine to say "keep doing", but not "keeping doing". However I believe your first sentence is correct. But I still have some doubt, because being a non native speaker I tend to rely on rules, and that rule forbids such constructions. But rules has always exceptions. But my point is there is a rule.

Answer (score 2):

Two gerunds cannot be put together when they both function as verb inflections:

> I am starting  ***eating** | **to eat** my breakfast.

If a gerund functions as a genuine noun, then another gerund can be put in front of it it, if that gerund functions as another noun, adjective, or verb inflection:

> Starting running again after many months of inactivity is difficult. [*verb*-ing + noun]
>
> The leaking plumbing was repaired. [adjective + noun]
>
> The marketing meeting went well. [noun + noun]

Answer (score 0):

The two examples you gave are not correct as written. They should be:

- The situation was *getting* irritating at that time.
- I am starting *to eat* my breakfast now.

There doesn't appear to be a consistent rule for two "-ing" words in a row, based on these examples.

Comment: Can you give few more examples where two -ing are together?

Comment: Joe was considering buying irritating bling. (I could insert a swear word to get five -ing's. Real foul language would go up to six).